# Round a float to a specific number of decimal places

Tags: haskell, floating-point, rounding

I'm trying to display a float but rounding it, so that

```
f = 5.545
```

Displays as : `5.55` while

```
f = 5.544
```

displays as : `5.54`

I've seen method to display only the two first decimals, but I want to have it rounded.

Thank you !

Comment: What do you currently use to display these numbers?

Comment: I use printf, and I can display 5.545 as 5.54, but I want it to be 5.55 since the 3rd decimal is a 5

Comment: When your implementation uses IEEE-754 binary64 for floating-point, **there is no number 5.545** in the type. That format represents numbers in a binary format, and the nearest number to 5.545 it can represent is 5.5449999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875. So display methods may show you “5.545”, but they are not showing the actual number. The fact that the number is **not** 5.545 is why rounding it to two decimal digits produces “5.54” and not “5.55”.

Comment: A consequence of this is that, as long as you are using the IEEE-754 binary64 format, **no rounding technique can cause 5.545 to be displayed as “5.55”** because it is impossible to pass 5.545 as a number to be rounded—that number does not exist in IEEE-754 binary64, and no algorithm can work on an input that is never passed to it. There may be other solutions, such as using formats other than the built-in floating-point type (e.g., use integer arithmetic as a manual fixed-point solution and format the results with your own code). You should explain more about the context of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't quite find a real solution to this, but I realised something :

Printf already does the job, but not exactly how I wanted.
Let's say I want to round 1.445, it will display 1.44. But if the number was 1.446, then it would have displayed 1.45.

Not exactly what I wanted, but close enough.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the way floating-point numbers are represented in the computer: they're actually in base-2, rather than base-10 (a bit of oversimplification, but good enough). As a consequence, when you type in `0.545`, the computer actually records that as `0.5499999999...` - very close to `0.545`, but slightly smaller. And since it's smaller than `0.545`, it's no wonder it gets rounded to `0.54`.

**If you really have to have exact base-10 numbers,** you should use [`Decimal`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.7/Decimal-0.5.1/Data-Decimal.html) instead of `Float` or `Double`. That package specifically takes care to represent floating-point numbers in base-10 without loss.

```
x :: Decimal
x = 0.545

show x
> "0.545"
```

The caveat is that `printf` does not support `Decimal`, so you'd have to display it by rounding via [`roundTo`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.7/Decimal-0.5.1/Data-Decimal.html#v:roundTo) and converting to string via `show`. Another caveat that `roundTo` does "banker's rounding" - if the last digit is five, it rounds to the nearest *even* digit, so we'd need to counteract that as a special case (I couldn't find a ready-to-use function that rounds by arithmetic rules):

```
displayDecimal :: Decimal -> String
displayDecimal x = show (rounded + compensate)
    where rounded = roundTo 2 x
          compensate = if (x - rounded) == 0.005 then 0.01 else 0

displayDecimal 0.545
> "0.55"

displayDecimal 0.5450000000001
> "0.55"

displayDecimal 0.544
> "0.54"

displayDecimal 0.5449999999999
> "0.54"
```

**However, if you just want this to work for numbers with three decimal places**, you can get away with just adding a very small value before rounding, like `0.00001`. This value is small enough that it won't mess up your actual numbers, but large enough to compensate for the base-2 vs. base-10 discrepancy:

```
displayRounded :: Double -> String            
displayRounded x = printf "%.2f" (x + 0.00001)

displayRounded 0.544
> "0.54"

displayRounded 0.545
> "0.55"
```

Comment: Adding 0.005 doesn't really work right, either... `printf "%.2f" (5.544 + 0.005)` produces `5.55`, but the correctly rounded answer is `5.54`.

Comment: Yes, @DanielWagner, I have totally misread the question, not once, but twice! :-/   Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: No matter how much you want it to work, adding a small epsilon before rounding simply *isn't correct*. It will give wrong answers for numbers near the rounding boundary. For example, try `displayDecimal 0.5441` or `displayRounded 0.544995`.

Comment: @DanielWagner With `displayDecimal` I just missed a zero (the delta needs to be two orders smaller than the rounding precision; corrected now), and `displayRounded` is explicitly prefixed with "If you just need this for numbers with three decimal places...", so the test case of `0.544995` doesn't count.

Comment: Making the epsilon smaller just means the bad cases have to be closer to the rounding boundary; it doesn't actually fix the problem. If you round `x + e` instead of rounding `x`, then setting `x = 0.5 - e/2` will produce a counterexample in the reals. (Admittedly this doesn't hold of `Double`; but by the time you make `e` small enough that this particular counterexample doesn't work for `Double`, you start causing yourself rounding errors for very large `x` instead.)

Comment: @DanielWagner Ok, you're right, the banker's round can't be defeated by the delta. But I _can_ just compensate for it as a special case.